# I don't want to miss the kabab ... don't be two lines away from each side, only 20%

Tags: html, css

I can not write a two-line box and it will be relatively continuous
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmOVx.jpg)

```
hr.hr-text {
margin:20px;
position: relative;
border: none;
height: 1px;
background: #999;
```

}

```
hr.hr-text::before {
    content: attr(data-content);
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.85rem;
    color: #999;
    border-radius: 30rem;
    padding: 0.2rem 2rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Can you share your html code also

Comment: <div class="mb-4">
            <!-- Gradient divider -->
         <hr data-content="kabab irani alferedo "
                id="gr1"
                class="hr-text bg-default solid mt-5 mb-5" />
        </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `white-space: nowrap;`

```
hr.hr-text::before {
    white-space: nowrap;
    content: attr(data-content);
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.85rem;
    color: #999;
    border-radius: 30rem;
    padding: 0.2rem 2rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```